# XSL / XPath syntax to select attributes NOT in a given namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given I am in the context of an xml element:

```
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
```

Will give me a copy of all attributes.  I am looking for an xpath expression which will give me all attributes *except* those in a given namespace, say 'x'
My current code of:

```
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(starts-with(name(),'x:'))]"/>
```

works but cant be the optimal answer.

NB Happy to learn about XSLT2.0 but looking for 1.0 answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you could write `<xsl:copy-of select="@* except @x:*"/>`. With XSLT 1.0 all you can do is use `<xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(namespace-uri() = 'http://example.com/')]"/>` (of course substituting `http://example.com/` with the namespace of your input attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I'm reluctant to use the uri directly simply as I hate having the uri in the xsl code twice.  Are there any efficiency advantages of this over my name() hack above?

Comment: No, efficiency is not different, but for the rare case of e.g. `<root xmlns:pf1="http://example.com/" xmlns:pf2="http://example.com/"><foo att1="value 1" pf1:att2="value 2" pf2:att3="value 3"/></root>` the `namespace-uri` checks finds both attributes while the `starts-with` check finds only one.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `xsl:copy-of`, do `xsl:apply-templates select="@*"`, and have two template rules

```
<xsl:template match="@*"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@x:*"/>
```

Comment: I was aware of this solution but given the number of times this is needed its a bit of a maintainence  nightmare